# Embedded HTTPS site in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an issue trying to **embedded** `https` site in an iframe.

I keep seeing it as this in my Chrome.

[image]

---

But if I visit the site first, click on **Advanced**

[image]

Then, click **proceed**

[image]

then, I can see the site in the iFrame.

[image]

---

How do I force embedded HTTPS site in iframe without having to go through those steps?

Is there any workaround or is it not even possible?

Comment: You should fix your certificate error.  In particular, you should use a domain name.

Comment: Gets a proper certificate or add the self signed certificate to your trusted store

Comment: Is your site http or https? http://www.tinywebgallery.com/blog/iframe-do-not-mix-http-and-https

Comment: @SLaks : What do you mean fix certificate error ? I don't owned the site. I embedded my partner's site. Do I need to request them for a special kind of permission or something ?

Comment: You should make sure that their page can load without any errors.

Comment: @wilkesybear : My site is locally http. It's private internally at the moment. It's not public yet unfortunately. :(

Comment: @SLaks : Their page will load `No Problem` if I visit it on the browser, click on advanced, and acknowledge it. Then, it will also appear to be fine on the iFrame as well.

Comment: @PeeHaa : Add the self signed certificate to my trusted store, can you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @ihue: _That is exactly the opposite of `No Problem`._  That is a very big problem that they should fix.

Comment: Isn't it the proper behavior for an HTTPS site. You will have to usually acknowledge it first before proceed ? What problem do they need to fix ? Do you mind ?

Comment: _Did you read any of the blaring red text on the error screen?_ This is **not OK**!

Comment: Is it mean that there cert is not ligit ? I can ask them purchase to the legit one. Do you think that will solve the problem that I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes.  If they actually set up HTTPS correctly with a real certificate, you will not get a big scary warning that tells you _four times_ that something is seriously wrong and they are not secure at all.  What did you think that warning is?

Comment: Ohh okay I got it. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 2):

You don't post the URL, but there is a reference in the error page to `192.237.179.29`.

This makes me think that the actual problem here may actually be that the iFrame is referenced *by IP address* instead of *by hostname*.

It is *very* uncommon to have SSL certificates that correctly map to an IP address. And by uncommon I mean that I don't even know if it is possible to register a certificate for an IP address.

If you know the proper hostname of the website that you are trying to reach, try to use that. Or tell the site owner to reference that iframe by hostname instead.

Comment: Yes, SSL certificates support IP addresses:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/x509v3_config.html

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks for your suggestion.